# Is it possible to connect objects at run time using and iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, interface-builder

I have an `.xib` file with two views one for landscape and other for portrait.It seams  impossible to connect two views to a single object, so that i can avoid repeating code for two variables or looping with array.

Is it possible to connect objects at run time in Cocoa?

Comment: Everything is an Object, What object you are talking about? Do you mean by which method should get performed when you touch up inside the button? if yes then just use addTarget method and give your desired selector name.

Comment: it is possible by adding UIButton programmatically..

Comment: please describe your problem more in order to understand better

Answer (score 1):

You can assign tag to those two views, and use viewWithTag method to get the one you need at run time then assign it to self.view or other view.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You Can use one .xib with two view.it is possible conditions are.

**1)** connect those views on .xib file,and with its IBOutlet objects.then you can show and hide on device orientation.

Comment: Hiding and showing every view is a difficult task,i want a different solution by reassign objects. is that possible?